# Why does my chainer LSTM example slow down after the first epoch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, chainer

Here's my sample LSTM class. Input ID's representing characters in a string of English text are encoded as one-hot vectors and fed into a single LSTM layer.

```py
class MyLSTM(Chain):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, hidden_size):
        super(MyLSTM, self).__init__(
            mid=L.LSTM(vocab_size, hidden_size),
            out=L.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size),
        )
        self.W = np.identity(vocab_size).astype(np.float32)

    def reset_state(self):
        self.mid.reset_state()

    def __call__(self, x):
        x_1hot = F.embed_id(x, self.W)
        h = self.mid(x_1hot)
        y = self.out(h)
        return y
```

Full code is here, just point it to a sample txt file and it should run:
https://gist.github.com/chris838/cea1987c38e0f29a2a514ad229454c0e

During the first epoch I'm running 20 iterations per second. By the 3rd epoch a single iteration is taking more than a second!

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well (although, not as bad - from processing 162 sentences/sec in epoch=1 to only 90 sent/sec at epoch=9, on a cpu). 
Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @TomerLevinboim pretty sure I didn't directly resolve this but if I had to guess I'd say it's something to do with truncating the backprop-through time, so that its a fixed length and not over the entire input so far?

Comment: I'm not sure why BPTT would degrade the running time... Anyway, the problem went away after I cleaned the code so I don't think it's Chainer's fault.